# SQL best way to subtract a value of the previous row in the query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to calculate the total lost machine time in the database. The columns in the table are MachineID aka PlantID, StartTime, EndTime.

In theory its simply sort the table by machineID and by StartTime then take the StartTime of the current row and subtract the previous rows EndTime.

Here is my current query that works:

```
SELECT SUM([StartTime] - [EndTime]) AS TotalLostTime  
FROM(SELECT * 
     FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [PlantID], [StartTime]) AS [Row],
                  [MachineRecords].PlantID , [MachineRecords].EndTime 
           FROM [MachineRecords]) AS a 
     JOIN (SELECT * 
           FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [PlantID], 
                                                        [StartTime]) AS [Row1],
                        [MachineRecords].PlantID as PlantID1 , 
                        [MachineRecords].StartTime 
                 FROM [MachineRecords]) as b) m 
     ON m.PlantID1 = a.[PlantID] 
        AND a.[Row] = m.[Row1]-1) lostTimeQuery
```

My question is: Is there a better(more consise) way of achieving the same result of this query?

Thanks for the help.

EDIT:

After the comment from wildplasser i've created this query:

```
SELECT SUM(a.StartTime - a.LagEnd) as LostTime 
FROM (SELECT [PlantID], [StartTime], [EndTime], 
             LAG([PlantID]) OVER (ORDER BY PlantID, StartTime) LagPlantID,
             LAG([EndTime]) OVER (ORDER BY PlantID, StartTime) LagEnd 
      FROM MachineRecords) a 
WHERE a.PlantID = a.LagPlantID
```

Comment: A window function, such as lag() ?

Comment: This does seem to be what im after :)

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?  Not all of them support that particular function.  Also, could we get a sample schema?  For example, if you have a (stored) sequence number _per plantId_ you don't need to calculate it on the fly.

Comment: From the ugly [FieldNames] you can conclude that he uses one of the Microsoft products. BTW: row_number() is also a window function but you'll have to handle the begin-of-group case (LEFT join+ COALESCE, basically)

Comment: Yes im using Visual Studio 2012 and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2010, this had to be written in VS2012 as the 2010 version Management Studio didn't have LAG as it was implemented in Microsoft SQL Server 2012. @Clockwork-Muse The plantID is not necessarily a sequence.

Comment: I didn't think `plantId` itself was a sequence...  Oh, if you've figured out the answer yourself, it's perfectly acceptable to post it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help Clockwork-Muse and wildplasser :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the resulting query I went with :)

```
SELECT SUM(a.StartTime - a.LagEnd) as LostTime 
FROM (SELECT [PlantID], [StartTime], [EndTime], 
             LAG([PlantID]) OVER (ORDER BY PlantID, StartTime) LagPlantID,
             LAG([EndTime]) OVER (ORDER BY PlantID, StartTime) LagEnd 
      FROM MachineRecords) a 
WHERE a.PlantID = a.LagPlantID
```