# Subtracting Previous Value by Prior Group - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This question has been asked previously and been well answered for MySQL specifically, however I'd very much appreciate your guys' help in translating this for SQL Server. The prior posts are closed and I didn't want to reopen them as they're quite old.

Below is the dataset to query, and the required output of the query solution. Below that is the excellent MySql solution posted here ([SQL best way to subtract a value of the previous row in the query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734976/sql-best-way-to-subtract-a-value-of-the-previous-row-in-the-query)). My question is how to accomplish the same result with variables in SQL Server. I apologize if this is a novice question, but I'm new to variables in SQL Server and have failed in my attempts to translate to SQL Server based on MSDN documentation on variables in SQL Server.

Thank you for your help!

```
select
      EL.SN,
      EL.Date,
      EL.EL.Value,
      if( @lastSN = EL.SN, EL.Value - @lastValue, 0000.00 ) as Consumption,
      @lastSN := EL.SN,
      @lastValue := EL.Value
   from
      EnergyLog EL,
      ( select @lastSN := 0,
               @lastValue := 0 ) SQLVars
   order by
      EL.SN,
      EL.Date
```

I need to have the consumption value base on previous one by SN number.
This is my data:

TABLE EnergyLog

```
SN     Date                 Value
2380   2012-10-30 00:15:51  21.01
2380   2012-10-31 00:31:03  22.04
2380   2012-11-01 00:16:02  22.65
2380   2012-11-02 00:15:32  23.11
20100  2012-10-30 00:15:38  35.21
20100  2012-10-31 00:15:48  37.07
20100  2012-11-01 00:15:49  38.17
20100  2012-11-02 00:15:19  38.97
20103  2012-10-30 10:27:34  57.98
20103  2012-10-31 12:24:42  60.83
```

This is the result I need:

```
SN      Date                 Value  consumption
2380    2012-10-30 00:15:51  21.01  0
2380    2012-10-31 00:31:03  22.04  1.03
2380    2012-11-01 00:16:02  22.65  0.61
2380    2012-11-02 00:15:32  23.11  0.46
20100   2012-10-30 00:15:38  35.21  0
20100   2012-10-31 00:15:48  37.07  1.86
20100   2012-11-01 00:15:49  38.17  1.1
20100   2012-11-02 00:15:19  38.97  0.8
20103   2012-10-30 10:27:34  57.98  0
20103   2012-10-31 12:24:42  60.83  2.85
```

Comment: what sql-server version are you using? because are better way to do that using analytics functions. Unless your requirement is use variables

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this question before, I am using SQL-Server 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using a CTE you would be able to get the data ordered, and then select the previous record.

```
WITH PREVCTE AS (
SELECT  *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SN ORDER BY MyDate) [RowNum] 
FROM @myTable
)
SELECT A.SN, 
       A.MyDate, 
       A.[Value], 
       A.[Value] - COALESCE(B.[Value], A.[Value]) [Consumption]
FROM PREVCTE A LEFT OUTER JOIN PREVCTE B 
    ON   A.RowNum - 1 = B.RowNum AND  
         A.SN = B.SN
```

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dd32c2/1)**

Comment: I have to leave my seat before finish my query, but was the same idea as yours, so I add my Fiddle to your answer.

Comment: Thank you again for this solution Steven, can you please help me better understand the function of COALESCE in this query? I know coalesce returns first non null expression, but i cant seem to grasp what it's doing here?

Comment: @TylerH The first row didn't have a preceding row so the outer join will give a null. The `coalesce` turns that into a zero.

Comment: thanks shawnt00, so the coalsce function turns the resulting calculation into a zero? that's the part that is hanging me up, i was thinking that it would convert the null/non-existent prior row value to zero, and then result in a calculation 21.01-0 = -21.01...the way it's working and that you have created is perfect, i wouldn't want the negative result, i'm just confused how that coalesce works. I guess that's exactly how it works, if one of the values contained in the coalesce parens is null, the calculation returns zero no matter what? Thanks again, sorry if i'm being dense here.

Comment: @TylerH The Coalesce will return the first instance of a not null value.  Here is a reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx  The query will return the value from the current row, if the previous row is null.  The result will be a 0 for the Consumption value.

Answer (score 0):

My previous solution had calculated running totals. After shawnt00's comment and looking back at the example that you've provided I see that's not the case. This should make a solution much easier. I believe that the following will work for SQL 2008, although I don't have a 2008 box handy at the moment to test it.

```
;WITH CTE_Ordered AS
(
    SELECT
        sn,
        [date],
        value,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY sn ORDER BY [date]) AS row_num
    FROM
        dbo.EnergyLog
)
SELECT
    T1.sn,
    T1.[date],
    T1.value,
    T1.value - COALESCE(T2.value, 0) AS consumption
FROM
    CTE_Ordered T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE_Ordered T2 ON
    T2.sn = T1.sn AND
    T2.row_num = T1.row_num - 1
ORDER BY
    T1.sn,
    T1.row_num
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!!! Unfortunately my workplace has SQL Server 2008 - is there a way you might suggest that is compatible with that?

Comment: I've added in a solution for SQL Server 2008

Comment: @TomH I think OP is looking for the difference between consecutive rows and not the running total.

Comment: Should be  `COALESCE(T2.value, T1.value)` so first value get 0 consumption.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for the difference between adjacent dates. Here's one way.

```
select
    SN, Date, Value,
    Value - (
        select coalesce(max(Value), 0) from EnergyLog el2
        where el2.SN = el.SN and el2.Date < el.Date
        group by el2.SN
    ) as consumption
from EnergyLog el
```

You might get a performance boost by narrowing the size of the look-back window if you can always assume the time between is capped. That's going to depending on indexing too.

```
select
    SN, Date, Value,
    Value - (
        select coalesce(max(Value), 0) from EnergyLog el2
        where el2.SN = el.SN
            and el2.Date > dateadd(hour, -48, el.Date) /* max gap 48 hrs? */
            and el2.Date < el.Date
        group by el2.SN
    ) as consumption
from EnergyLog el
```

EDIT: Based on your comment below regarding sequence numbers:

```
select
    SN, Date, Value,
    Value - (
        select coalesce(max(Value), 0) from EnergyLog el2
        where el2.SN = el.SN and el2.SeqNo = el.SeqNo - 1
        group by el2.SN
    ) as consumption
from EnergyLog el
```

You can certainly use an outer join rather than the scalar subquery. Of course if you already have a sequence number then you won't need `row_number()` to generate them.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions, I am grateful! I will test these ideas out today - to clarify, my use case is actually distinct from the example i provided - but the same concept. With my actual data, i have a sequence number to order the records by, rather than a date. I apologize for not adding that or providing my actual data - I just wanted to reuse the previous  post so that the conversation around that. Thanks again for your help!